# Determine the area of the region bounded by $y=2e^x$, $ y=e^{2x}$ and $x=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, definite-integrals

$$y_1 = 2e^x$$
$$y_2 = e^{2x}$$
$$x=0$$

I was thinking of finding the $x$-intercepts first, so $2e^x= e^{2x}$.

What is next?

Answer (score 1):

Think of the equation as:$$2e^x=(e^x)^2.$$Let $z=e^x$.  What is the resulting equation? How would you solve it?

Comment: thank you! it helped me a lot actually.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already know Double Integration. If you don't, wait for someone else's answer.
Once you find the intercept, call it $z$,

Area = $\displaystyle \int_{x=0}^{x=z}\int_{y=e^{2x}}^{y=2e^x}dy.dx$